# SQL Query that gives output data in two columns

Tags: sql

We have a MySQL SQL table named "Sales" with 3 columns of data: Account_ID, Spend_Date, and Spend_Amount. We store one row for each account, and every day they are active, a few rows of sample data below:

[image: Sales Table]

How can I write a SQL query that gives me output data in two columns: 1) Account_ID, and 2) the date of which account has the highest Spend_Amount on record?

Comment: You may want to add which SQL dialect this is about. The answer could be (and probably is) different between for example MySQL and Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

One method is to use an aggregation query to get the maximum spend amount per account.  Then join this back to the original data to get the date information:

```
select s.*
from sales s join
     (select account_id, max(spend_amount) as maxsa
      from sales
      group by account_id
     ) ss
     on s.account_id = ss.account_id and s.spend_amount = ss.maxsa;
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks right to me. Is this MySQL code? I meant to say it's a MySQL table.

Comment: @Eric . . . This is standard SQL and works in MysQL.

Answer (score -1):

you should do something like this :

```
select Account_ID,Spend_Data from Sales order by Spend_Amount desc;
```

in this way it returns a list of records. The first on top is what you are looking for

Comment: This does not give a single result per account_id which afaict the question is about.